# Problemas ao Crirar display flex no css

Tags: css, html5

Olá, eu estou tentando programar um site que utiliza 3 caixas verticais centralizadas na tela,porém quando tento criar as caixas pelo display flex, elas simplesmente não funcionam, eu ja tentei de tudo e nada funciona. alguém poderia me ajudar ? segue abaixo o codigo da pagina

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Site Teste</title>

  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

  <div class="box Sedans">
  <h2>Sedans</h2> 
  <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city 
    or on your next road trip.</p>
   </div>

<div class="box SUVs">
  <h3>SUVs</h3>

  <p>An SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation 
    and off-road adventures.</p> 
  </div>

<div class="box Luxury">
  <h4>Luxury</h4>

  <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury 
    rental and arrive in style.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

aqui abaixo o codigo do CSS

```
.container{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.box{
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.Sedans {
    background-color: blue;
}

.Suvs{
    background-color: aqua;
}

.Luxury{
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Olá Carlos. O que tu queres dizer com simplesmente não funcionam? Há alguma mensagem de erro? Há um comportamento inesperado? Tu poderias descrever?

Comment: eu esperava o comportamento de criar uma caixa separada para cada div com a background-color que coloquei no css

Answer (score 0):

quando voce usa o flex-direction: column, ele inverte os eixos, ou seja se voce não está conseguindo por eles ao centro pode ser que tenha que por um align-item:center; e ele irá centralizar no eixo Y e utilize o justifi-content:center, e ele ajustará ao eixo X

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

creio que tenhas que tirar o class box para uma div por cima!